# Can't login to Fabric in Unity, getting "Network error!" message

Tags: unity-game-engine, crashlytics, google-fabric

When I try to login to fabric in Unity I get this message in console:

> [Fabric] An exception has occured; Error writing request: The
>   authentication or decryption has failed.

Target platform is iOS.

Comment: This is a bug on Fabric's end and we're working on a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. Unfortunately, we made a mistake when we re-issued a certificate for our fabric.io domains on Sept 26 which requires that you re-download and import the Unity plugin into your project. Sorry for this, but once you download version 1.2.8 or higher from https://fabric.io/downloads/unity, you'll be all set.

Comment: It's fixed. Thanks

Comment: in unity 2017 - it's show up as 1.2.5& What Im doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're referencing the version of the SDK v the version of the Fabric package.

Comment: Hi there,
I'm new using Fabric and I cant get it to connect inside Unity.
I get the same error "Network Error!" and a little dig around show me there is an Exception: ("Error writing request: The authentication or decryption has failed.")
I'm using the 1.2.8 version

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this on the latest unity plugin. Do you have any other proxies or firewalls that could interfere?

Comment: I didnt notice that I had multi error when importing the plugin:
"Failed to Initialize valildator", "An error occured when trying to fetch the dependency graph; Error getting response stream (Write: The authentication or decryption has failed.)" then "Dependency graph is empty, skipping update check..."
our game uses network without problem so I dont think the editor has restrictions. I also checked my firewall config and found that I had some entry-network block on UnityEditor and MonoDevelop which I removed. Still not working

Comment: I have the same problem, created a new empty project in Unity 2017.4.10f1. Import newest fabric plugin. Click Prepare fabric. And it it say Network Error!

Comment: Update, I switched to another PC. This time it worked. Maybe something in old fabric sdk config is still in this PC.

Comment: Very strange, but glad you're all set.